# Two tables - One output - No Variables

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a query that cannot contain any variables. This query will be pasted into a third party program that uses SQL commands, but seems to lack the ability to use variables, which is very unfortunate for me.

I have two tables that do not share any relationship other than they both contain one field that is the same ("PartNo").
The tables are OrderDet and BinLocations.
What I am essentially trying to combine into one table are these two queries.

```
SELECT OrderDet.PartNo, COUNT(OrderDet.PartNo) AS [Number Of Orders], SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Total to Make]
FROM OrderDet
WHERE OrderDet.Status = 'Open' AND OrderDet.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber'
GROUP BY OrderDet.PartNo
```

The Other is:

```
SELECT SUM(BinLocations.QtyOnHand) AS [Total Available]
FROM BinLocations
WHERE BinLocations.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber'
GROUP BY BinLocations.PartNo
```

I am able to come up with a query that forces me to have "two" xxx.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber' in it, but my issue is I am forced to only have a single xxx.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber' because where this is being used creates a prompt for the user to enter a part number, but it only allows one entry.

Whats happening now is there are multiple orders with this 'SomePartNumber' and there are multiple BinLocations with this "SomePartNumber" and when I try to join these tables, I do not got a single row output containing the sums of each table, I get duplicates created and the sums are incorrect.

I am looking for a response like this:

`[PartNo]  [Open Orders][Total Make Qty][Total On Hand][Qty Left Over]
5810098-2    1             150              2633           2483`

I was reading other posts waiting for this to be answered and came across a post that used 'WITH'. I came up with a possible solution but maybe someone can spot where there might be an issue?

```
WITH Bins AS
(SELECT BinLocations.PartNo, SUM(BinLocations.QtyOnHand) AS [Total On Hand] FROM BinLocations GROUP BY BinLocations.PartNo)
SELECT OrderDet.PartNo, COUNT(OrderDet.PartNo) AS [Open Orders], SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Total Make Qty], Bins.[Total On Hand],
Bins.[Total On Hand] - SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Qty Left Over]
FROM OrderDet, Bins
WHERE OrderDet.Status = 'Open' AND OrderDet.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber' AND Bins.PartNo = OrderDet.PartNo
GROUP BY OrderDet.PartNo, Bins.[Total On Hand]
```

Ok, well while this works for me in sql, the program I past this into will not accept the "With" command either. Seems very limited.
Any way to make that command without using the "With" Statment?

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results and actual results. (As text not images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `With CTE` query is working fine inside SQL env, then it can rewritten in this manner:

```
SELECT 
    OrderDet.PartNo, 
    COUNT(OrderDet.PartNo) AS [Open Orders], 
    SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Total Make Qty], 
    Bins.[Total On Hand],
    Bins.[Total On Hand] - SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Qty Left Over]
FROM 
    OrderDet
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         BinLocations.PartNo, 
         SUM(BinLocations.QtyOnHand) AS [Total On Hand] 
     FROM 
         BinLocations 
     GROUP BY 
         BinLocations.PartNo) Bins ON Bins.PartNo = OrderDet.PartNo
WHERE 
    OrderDet.Status = 'Open' 
    AND OrderDet.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber' 
GROUP BY 
    OrderDet.PartNo, Bins.[Total On Hand]
```

Why aren't you using a stored procedure?

Comment: Stored procedures was my first attempt, but the application will not except “EXEC”, “WITH”, “@“, and probably others. 
Seems it only like basic SQL syntax. 
I’ll give this solution a try. I also had a thought or maybe using a third intermediate table as a bridge between these two. 
I’ll respond back with the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query.. I feel it should give you one row..

```
Select * from 
(
SELECT 
    OrderDet.PartNo
    ,COUNT(OrderDet.PartNo) AS [Number Of Orders]
    ,SUM(OrderDet.QtyToMake) AS [Total to Make]
FROM 
    OrderDet
WHERE 
    OrderDet.Status = 'Open' 
    AND OrderDet.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber'
GROUP BY 
    OrderDet.PartNo
) t
JOIN
(
SELECT 
    SUM(BinLocations.QtyOnHand) AS [Total Available]
    ,PartNo
FROM 
    BinLocations
WHERE 
    BinLocations.PartNo = 'SomePartNumber'
GROUP BY 
    BinLocations.PartNo
) t1
ON t.PartNo = t1.PartNo;
```

Comment: This would fail where I need to copy it into as it has two check if something is equal to 'SomePartNumber'. I appreciate the response.